# How to send data from Perl to Python

Tags: android, python, perl, ipc, jython

I asked another question about speeding up the process of testing Android with Perl and Monkeyrunner (Jython) and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10859055/1016937).

Starting a Monkeyrunner script, getting an object once and then waiting in a cycle for the data to come from a Perl script (processing it when it comes) seems a great idea. But I don't know how to setup some sort of IPC between Perl and Jython (Python). How can I do it?

Comment: You would need to write a wrapper in Python to handle the communication and give the data to the Monkeyrunner thing. Have you googled/looked at tutorials or docs for how to achieve IPC in Python at all? Does your Perl script need to receive results? A TCP-connection might work for that. For Perl, look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html.

Answer (score 3):

Just use stdin in your `monkeyrunner` script to read commands from your perl script, which should open a pipe to it:

```
 while True:
    cmd = raw_input('Enter command: ')
    if cmd == 'q' or cmd == 'Q':
        break
```